# jQuery form submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When I submit below form the current page is refreshed and form parameters are appended to the end of the page URL. Why is this occuring ? I need to submit the form but the keep the form parameters hidden.

Thanks

```
<div class="ui-block-b"><button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button></div>

            $("#submit").click(function(){

                var formData = $("#newPostForm").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/mobile/newpost.php",
                    cache: false,
                    data: formData,
                    success: onSuccess
                });

                return false;
            });
```

Comment: Change the button type from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` and it won't refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `type="submit"` (which by the why should actually be `<input type="submit">`) and just make it a standard button if you don't plan on actually submitting the form:

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

An alternative method would be to set an `onsubmit` handler on the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#newPostForm").submit(function(){

    var formData = $("#newPostForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/mobile/newpost.php",
      cache: false,
      data: formData,
      success: function(data) {
         window.location.href = "/where/to/go";
      }
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, so to redirect once the form is submitted, that should go into the success: onSuccess function call ?

Comment: @user470184 See the updated inline code on how to achieve a redirect on success

Comment: I was thinking of trying to redirect to url: "/mobile/newpost.php". I just want to check the parameters I submit.